# Interactive response not shown on Slack

Tags: python-3.x, flask, slack, slack-api

I am developing a simple Slack app with Python and Flask.
It should respond to a slash command with a message containing a button. And it respond to the user clicking the button.

The problem is: The response message to the interactive message request is not posted in the Slack channel after clicking the button.

### Details

After clicking the button I can see the request coming in on my Python console e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2019 17:30:09] "POST /interactive HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And I can see my app responding to this request on my ngrok inspect page:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK    
Content-Type: application/json    
Content-Length: 25    
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.0    
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 15:41:57 GMT

{
  "text": "Hi there"
}
```

But the response message will not be shown on Slack.
Also there is no service error shown on Slack, so it seams Slack is getting a 200 OK response.

Also if I send my interactive response to the `response_url` it works fine. Just trying to respond directly to the HTTP request does not.

Interestingly I am using the exact same approach to respond to the slash command and the interactive request. It works for the first but not for the latter.

### Setup

I am running my app in debug mode on Python development server on port 8000. The server is exposed to Slack using ngrok. ngrok has my external URL mapped to `localhost:8000`. The app is started from within Visual Studio Code.

The request URLs are configured correctly to the respective endpoints for both slash command and interactive action.

### Code

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, json

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/slash', methods=['POST'])
def slash_response():                
    """ endpoint for receiving all slash command requests from Slack """

    # blocks defintion from message builder
    # converting from JSON to array
    blocks = json.loads("""[
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Please select an option:",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Click me",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "button_1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]""")

    # compose response message    
    response = {
        "blocks": blocks
    }

    ## convert response message into JSON and send back to Slack
    return json.jsonify(response)

@app.route('/interactive', methods=['POST'])
def interactive_response():                
    """ endpoint for receiving all interactivity requests from Slack """

    # compose response message    
    response = {
        "text": "Hi there"
    }

     ## convert response message into JSON and send back to Slack
    return json.jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000) #run app in debug mode on port 8000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a section on the Slack API page that explains what's going on with your interactive component!

Everything I am about to go over is in the [Responding to the interaction](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity#ack) section of the official documentation.

There are two steps to responding to an interaction:

1. Acknowledgment response - send an OK 200 back to slack within 3 seconds of receiving the request payload. The text you send with this response will not alter the contents of the current slack message.
2. Composed response - send your updated message to slack using a POST request and the response_url they package in the request payload.

So the reason OP's code does not work is that Slack does no longer accept a full message as direct response to an interaction. Instead all response messages need to be send to the `response_url`.

However, to enable backwards compatibility it is still possible to respond directly with message including attachments, but not with messages containing layout blocks.

## Code

Here is the code I used to substitute the original button message with the text "Hi Erik!"

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, json, request

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/slash', methods=['POST'])
def slash_response():                
    """ endpoint for receiving all slash command requests from Slack """

    # blocks defintion from message builder
    # converting from JSON to array
    blocks = json.loads("""[
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Please select an option:",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Click me",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "button_1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]""")

    # compose response message    
    response = {
        "blocks": blocks
    }

    ## convert response message into JSON and send back to Slack
    return json.jsonify(response)

@app.route('/interactive', methods=['POST'])
def interactive_response():                
    """ endpoint for receiving all interactivity requests from Slack """
    # compose response message   
    data = json.loads(request.form["payload"])
    response = {
        'text': 'Hi Erik!', 
        }

    requests.post(data['response_url'], json=response)
    return '' 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000) #run app in debug mode on port 8000
```

Comment: If you wanted to delete an ephemeral message this way you could change the response to 
    response = {
            'response_type': 'ephemeral', 
            'text': '', 
            'replace_original': 'true',
            'delete_original':'true'
        }

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It's not 100% clear from the answer, but you indeed found the problem. Slack does no longer accept a full message as direct response. Instead you must send them to the `response_url`. I will add that info to your answer to make it more clear.